# Intellisense autocomplete inserting text in wrong places

Tags: razor, ide, visual-studio-2019, intellisense, code-editor

When writing code in cshtml files, sometimes intellisense goes haywire and starts writing text several lines above where I am actually typing. At the moment it seems to be limited to when I hit the tab key to let it finish a property name which isn't too bad because I can just not do that. However, it also seems to happen at other times like just when I type @Model and then press a period it might write the word Model in some other part of the code file.

Anyone know how to correct this?

Comment: Could you please more info or some screenshots to describe your issue?

Comment: Next time it happens I will. 
It probably happens about once a week. For a screenshot, just imagine the word Model being inserted at some totally random position in the editor after you type @Model and then a dot. I 'think' it typically happens when I write razor code in javascript. And it seems to work better if you're typing between double quotes.

Comment: When you faced the issue next time, please try to close vs, delete `.vs` hidden folder, `bin` and `obj` folder, then restart your project.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Thanks, I will try that! FYI, I just had a similar but different issue last night where when I pressed tab to have it automatically finish the highlighted property in the intellisense menu it would write some piece of text that had absolutely nothing to do with the property selected. Again, this was in a razor file. Hopefully deleting those folders will resolve both issues though.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT and btw I do plan to come back and comment on whether I encounter the issue again but I will wait a few days to make sure it's really gone. Feel free to tag me after that in another comment if I forget and you'd like to here my response though.

Comment: Ok. Got that. If you faced the same issue later, please do not forget to provide some pics.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT I am getting same issue, on 16.9.4.  I thought I was going mad!  Exact same behavior, sometimes the word "Model" inserted in random places, sometimes many lines away from where I was typing.  Also when I do tab completion, if often creates two copies of intellisense text.  Seems to occur most often when entering Razor code into the middle of JavaScript code.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Just as a follow up wanted to let you know I haven't seen the issue reappear.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT I do still get an ArgumentException at various times like mellamokb mentions in his post though.

Answer (score 2):

This would probably fit better as a VS Feedback item, but since this is the only place I have found someone referencing the same issue, I thought I would add some confirmation.  I do not have a solution, only more examples to add.  This issue has been annoying me for months!  It seems to happen most often when typing razor code inside of JavaScript, especially inside of a quoted string.

Here is an example from a test project, where I am attempting to put a reference to a model field into a JavaScript string.  Notice that I click tab a couple times and it doesn't actually insert the intellisense result at the point I am typing.  But when I scroll down you can see it inserted it randomly in another spot pretty far away!

[image: Sample Issue]

I did also try to remove the hidden .vs folder, bin/, and obj/ and could still reliably reproduce the issue after restarting Visual Studio.  Currently on 1 before the latest (16.9.4).  I did notice that if I re-open this cshtml file, wait until the file seems to be fully loaded (all the red errors go away), I also reliably get an ArgumentException that occurs as I begin typing.  Then when I scroll down I already see that `Model` has been randomly inserted in another spot in the code.

[image: ArgumentException]

I'm going to try updating to latest (16.9.5), and starting in Safe Mode to skip loading all 3rd-party libraries, and see if the issue is still reproducible, in case it is caused by one of the handful of extensions I am currently using.

**Edit**: Well same issue with 16.9.5.  Trying to use Safe Mode is a no go, it makes the intellisense and syntax coloring completely disabled for .cshtml files.

Comment: I didn't even mention the ArgumentException because I had no idea how to reproduce and it seemingly happens so randomly, but I still get that too even though my main issue seems to be resolved for the moment.